# How to use request-promise to post to a HTTPS server with basic authentication?

Tags: node.js, paypal, https

I want to send post request to paypal https server to get a token
I was wondering if I can use module like request-promise
my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const paypalConfig = require('../config/paypal.config');
router.post('/get-token', (req, res) => {
            const orderBody = req.body;

    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(`${paypalConfig.client_id}:${paypalConfig.secret}`).toString('base64')
        },
        uri: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
        body: {
            grant_type: 'client_credentials'
        },
        json: true
    };

    requestPromise(options)
        .then(function(parsedBody) {
            console.log(parsedBody);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

that's too simple generate a certificate as well as key for your server , and implement like this.

```
var debug = require('debug')('my-application');
var app = require('../app');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.txt'),//set your key here
    cert: fs.readFileSync('crt.txt')//set your certificate here
};

https.createServer(options,app).listen(7012);//just put your port no which your server no is running
```

Comment: He's asking about `calling` the API of a HTTPS server. And not about `creating` one.